# C# why is duplicating object record when persist?

Tags: c#, linq, duplicates, entity-framework-6

Im using localDB on C#, and some class (context class) have attributes that is another class, but when i persist that object he dont only save the references of the attribute class (class_id) but duplicates the entire attribute class again. (Persist boths)

```
public class Item
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}   

public class Order
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

Both class have an extra control class that do basic the same routine to persist:

```
    public void SaveObjeto(ObjectClass object)
    {
        if (object.Id == 0)
        {
            ctx.Objects.Add(objeto);
        }
        else
        {
            var temp = ctx.Objects.SingleOrDefault(
                           temp => temp.Id == objeto.Id
                       );
            temp.Id = objeto.Id;
            temp.Attribute = objeto.Attribute;
        }

        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I use Linq expressions to make the persist.

Pratical Example:

- I have Class Item1 well persisted on LocalDB;
- Then i try to persist an class Order1 that have the attribute Item1
- When persist Order1 they create another record on LocalDB as Item1 (clone?) instead of just refer the already persisted Item1;
- In the end of all, i have stucked with two Item1 persisted on LocalDB.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you use a new instance of Item1 (probably with the same ID as that of the persisted record in the database) everytime a new Order instance is created. But then EF would track it as a newly added object. There are a couple of options:

1. Load Item1 from the db context and use it to assign the property in the order instance, which lets EF know that the entity is already persisted in tbe database.
2. Explcitly mark the Item1 as Unchanged/Detached so that EF would skip it.

   ```
   ctx.Entry(order.Item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
   ```

Comment: Thanks, i gonna give a shot for theses tips.

Comment: Both solutions worked well for me, i will use the second one because fits bettter for my project. Thank u.

Comment: But when the object attribute still have more objects attributes, is better recover him from context again instead of mark him as unchanged.

Comment: You may use either of the approaches    depending on what best suits your need..if the answer helped you, please  mark it as answer :)